# Rails request_url getting undefined local variable in Mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails 3.2 app, I'm trying to use the browser URL in a Mailer and it's view.

Here is the code from `views/comment_mailer/comment_email.html.erb`:

```
<% fromurl = request_url %>
```

Also tried:

```
<% fromurl = request.url %>
```

But, I get this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `request_url' for ...
```

In the debugger (better-errors gem), if I type `request`, I get nil.

Thanks for the help!

UPDATE1:

My issue seems to only be in the mailer and it's view.  If I put the same code in a normal view, it works fine. I even tried adding helper code in `helper/application_helper.rb` that gets the URL.  It works in other views, but in the mailer view I get `undefined local variable or method`.

Comment: When you say "in the debugger", are you talking about the IRB console? Or maybe with `binding.pry`? Because in a view executed by an HTTP request, the variable `request` would never be `nil`. It is odd that in your case, `request` is `nil`.

Comment: I"m using the gem better-errors.  It gives me a Rails console at error time.

Comment: Can you call `<%= request.inspect %>` in your view and check if it is `nil` or something else? (don't let the error happen because you will end up with the better-errors' console and I suspect it to change the `request` variable for its context, that's what I am trying to prove by asking you to output `request.inspect`)

Comment: I guess in EMAIL template you should not use `request`, because there are no http requests when you get an e-mail

Comment: `undefined method `inpect' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: i think `request` variable is only accesible in controllers. you can try this by writing it in controller method `@fromurl = request_url` and access it in view `<% @fromurl %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `request` is not available in the mailer, if you want to use the request url then store it elsewhere and retrieve it

There is [`actionmailer_with_request`](https://github.com/weppos/actionmailer_with_request) which already does that for example.

If you use a server such as puma, I recommend that you fork (or find a fork) which uses an alternative to `Thread.current` such as [`RequestStore`](https://github.com/steveklabnik/request_store) to store the request (I opened an issue about that).

Comment: I put code in the ApplicationController = `$request_url = request.url`. Now I can access `$request_url` in my controllers.